# Does my LED panel require a gap between it and the ceiling for cooling?

Tags: ceiling, led

I've just bought an ultra slim LED panel that I was going to stick directly to a painted plaster ceiling with silicon or No-More-Nails. The back of the panel is made of a thin plastic sheet and well attached to the rest of the light. However I've just seen many people use a ceiling frame kit which leaves a small gap behind.

Is there a particular reason to leave a gap between the panel and the ceiling, such as overheating issues?

Link to LED Panel:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00WT2BCZO

Link to Frame:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Panel-Surface-Mounting-Ceiling-Silver/dp/B01AV0VNQI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like all types of lighting, The LEDs in LED panels generate much more heat than light. LEDs are more efficient than traditional incandescent lights and generate less heat but still generate a lot and are much much less tolerant of overheating.

The 600x600 panels are designed for standard suspended ceilings as used in offices - there will normally be a large air gap above them, certainly tens of cm.

Therefore I would be very cautious about mounting them directly to a ceiling with no air gap above the panel. I'd expect a considerably shortened life for the LED panels and the possibility of at least minor heat damage to the ceiling.

Heat may degrade your adhesive and cause it to fail and potentially cause injuries to anyone below. I note that No-More-Nails have only one product that is advertised as "temperature resistant" and even that is only good up to 90C. I suspect their "original" product will fail at much lower temperatures.

Comment: Thanks I might run a test with the back covered and see what temp it gets to. I've just spotted in the original amazon description that it can be surface mounted, but will take that with a pinch of salt! Also might look at screwing the thing somehow.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of airflow wouldn't hurt when dealing with electronics/transformers (though I assume this is a electronic transformer so much less heat is generated). If you don't want a frame just use some simple spacers like scrap wood or metal you have lying around the house. I wouldn't use glue on this though as I don't want this thing crashing down on you. I would play it safe and use some screws.